# Remove Decimal like " [Decimal('1220'), Decimal('160')] "from Django Queryset results

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I have a *queryset result* which I would like to **put into a list of Data** and a list of Labels for Chart.js **without showing** **Decimal**.
In my view.py the following funtion based view is written:

```
labels = []
data = []
total_transactions_by_user =  filtered_transaction_query_by_user.values('coin__name').annotate( total = (Sum('trade_price' ) * Sum('number_of_coins') ) ).order_by('-total')

for each in total_transactions_by_user:
    labels.append(each["coin__name"])
    data.append(each["total"])
```

The results of the lists are:

```
['Bitcoin', 'Dogecoin']

[Decimal('1220'), Decimal('160')]
```

How do I remove Decimal() ,so I have 1220, and 160 in my List[]

My goal is to replicate the situation of this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2020/01/19/how-to-use-chart-js-with-django.html

Comment: It doesn't matter that a `print(data)` outputs a `Decimal` representation. Very much reading between the lines here: you want to pass this to Javascript? As… JSON? Then it's important that the `Decimal` is correctly converted at that point when converting it to JSON. Whatever it is until then is not important.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. I dont want to pass it as JSON, just as a list of floats. My goal is to replicate this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2020/01/19/how-to-use-chart-js-with-django.html

Comment: You want to pass it to Javascript, and Javascript doesn't understand Python lists, so you need to convert it to some format Javascript does understand, of which JSON is the obvious choice. Note that Python literals and Javascript/JSON look very very similar on the surface, but are not interchangeable.

Comment: Allright, Thank you

Comment: Decimal type is problem with Pandas dataframe too. Float type is no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested by @deceze I need to shift my thinking to covert the queryset to Json then use it in Chart.js
Thank for the help.